# Thread-Safeness of FloatToStr / DateToStr

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, delphi-xe

I just found in the documentation that `FloatToStr` and `DateToStr` are not thread-safe in their one-paramater overloads. The reason is that they access localization information stored in global variables.

My question is: is this of any practical relevance if I do not change the format settings at runtime? As far as I understand it, I'm on the safe side as long as everyone only reads the format settings - even from multiple threads.

Is that true or am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you doing in your threads? Are you using those functions just for output to UI or do you need the output of those functions for something else?

Comment: @The_Fox: for something else. I store date values in a string field.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FloatToStr, DateToStr and others similar functions are reading global format settings. So, if your application does not change these settings for these function calls, then it is thread safe. The following code on opposite is not thread safe:

```
DecimalSeparator := ',';
try
  s := FloatToStr(123.45);
finally
  DecimalSeparator := '.';
end;
```

When you need the tread safety and "local" format settings, then you have to use overloaded functions, which take as last parameter: AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings. So, to make above code thread safe you have to write:

```
var
  fs: TFormatSettings;

GetLocaleFormatSettings(GetThreadLocale, fs);
fs.DecimalSeparator := ',';
s := FloatToStr(123.45, fs);
```

Notes:

1. GetLocaleFormatSettings and fs initialization may be called once and then fs may be used multiple times. This will speedup the code.
2. Instead of GetLocaleFormatSettings may be used TFormatSettings.Create. I am not sure when that was introduced, but I see that in Delphi XE.

Comment: This is not true (or no longer true?), see The_Fox's answer!

Answer (score 4):

Even the global settings can change when Application.UpdateFormatSettings (Delphi 7, don't know about Delphi XE) is True. When a user changes the Regional and Language options of Windows, this will be reflected in your application. You can circumvent this by setting UpdateFormatSettings to False, but even then you can't be sure, maybe there is some third party library you use that changes it.

I had some problems with our own application: Nowhere in our application the global formatsettings were changed, but still there was information loss because a float was converted to a string and when the string was converted back to float, the formatsettings were magically changed. (So you had this: 1.2 -> convert to string -> '1.2' -> black magic that changed formatsettings.decimalseparator -> convert to float -> 12).

My suggestion: only use the not thread-safe version for UI purposes so the user sees dates and floats the way he likes them to see, for everything else, use the thread-safe version. Conversions inside your application will then be consistent and don't give surprises.

Answer (score 3):

If the global settings are not changed by another thread while `FloatToStr` or `DateToStr` are executed you are fine.

EDIT: one thing to keep in mind:

```
var
  // Note: Using the global FormatSettings variable corresponds to using the
  // individual global formatting variables and is not thread-safe.
  FormatSettings: TFormatSettings absolute CurrencyString;
```

The global variable above is just an alias for the global variables listed below. It is possible to change them either through the `FormatSettings` variable or directly.

```
var
  // Important: Do not change the order of these declarations, they must
  // match the declaration order of the fields in TFormatSettings exactly!
  CurrencyString: string deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.CurrencyString';
  CurrencyFormat: Byte deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.CurrencyFormat';
  CurrencyDecimals: Byte deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.CurrencyDecimals';
  DateSeparator: Char deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.DateSeparator';
  TimeSeparator: Char deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.TimeSeparator';
  ListSeparator: Char deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.ListSeparator';
  ShortDateFormat: string deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat';
  LongDateFormat: string deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.LongDateFormat';
  TimeAMString: string deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.TimeAMString';
  TimePMString: string deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.TimePMString';
  ShortTimeFormat: string deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat';
  LongTimeFormat: string deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.LongTimeFormat';
  ShortMonthNames: array[1..12] of string deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.ShortMonthNames';
  LongMonthNames: array[1..12] of string deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.LongMonthNames';
  ShortDayNames: array[1..7] of string deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.ShortDayNames';
  LongDayNames: array[1..7] of string deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.LongDayNames';
  ThousandSeparator: Char deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.ThousandSeparator';
  DecimalSeparator: Char deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator';
  TwoDigitYearCenturyWindow: Word deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.TwoDigitYearCenturyWindow';
  NegCurrFormat: Byte deprecated 'Use FormatSettings.NegCurrFormat';
```

Comment: I'm with Thorsten on this - and I'm pretty confident about this

Answer (score 0):

I just had problem with decimal separator. Delphi's streaming system (readcomponent/writecomponent etc) simply changes it to '.' and after all the work is done, it is changed back to whatever it was.

So, when I used this system for my own purposes (serializing/deserializing rather complex structure) and decided to do it in separate thread, or even in several separate threads, it shot me to the leg: '.' were mixed with ',' somewhere.

Unfortunately, I saw in some other libraries when DecimalSeparator is simply changed in procedure with intention to change it back at the end (most careful ones put it in 'finally' clause), so if some of your code is executed when one of these libs are running in separate thread, using thread-safe versions of StrToFloat etc. is imperative.