# Is it OK to use DecimalSeparator to force Floattostr/Strtofloat functions to use a decimal point

Tags: delphi

Currently, I'm setting DecimalSeparator to a '.' in each procedure which uses these functions.

It would be much easier to set this globally at the start of the program but I found Delphi seems to periodically set this back to the current locale.

I need to make sure that a decimal point is used for all conversions no matter which country the program is used in as this is the standard for this type of program and all files structure and communication protocols, numeric displays in forms/edits etc are required to be formatted in this way.

I've been told in another thread that using decimalseparator is not the correct way to do it but I was not given any alternatives. The other threads concerning this subject that I've read don't seem to offer any formative guidance or are overly complex.

Is there a simple 'correct' way to do this ?

Comment: Which version of delphi?

Comment: 2007, Actually the apps were started in D5 and thats the version I found that the DecimalSeperator was being reset. Not sure if 2007 has this behaviour as the code was already altered when ported.

Comment: Follow the advice by NGLN using `FormatSettings`, it's the only way to assure a correct functionality.

Comment: See also [Thread-Safeness of FloatToStr / DateToStr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6055369/576719) for more input how to use `FormatSettings`.

Comment: Why not to respect user's locale preferences? And briefly switch to the "basic" locale only for cases of data exchange, etc.

Comment: @user539484 I've been bitten too many times to allow that.

Comment: @user539484: There are cases where it is a horribly bad idea to respect the current locale settings. One such case is if you are writing a mathematical software (like my own AlgoSim) or a scripting language interpreter, or even a compiler. (What if Delphi started to use commas as decimal separators in source code?)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, you only gave your own software a bad advertisement. Even mathematicians around the globe have regional preferences in notation.

Comment: @user539484: You don't know what you are talking about. AlgoSim is like Mathematica, Maple, or Matlab (yes, they all force periods as decimal separator), that is, kind of like Delphi, where you write scripts. If a comma was used as decimal separator, then how in the world would you tell the difference between the decimal separator and the argument separator? And why doesn't this compile in Delphi? `myfloat := 1,3 + 6,9;`? I told Windows to use commas as decimal separators!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, it appears what you are mathematician and i am merely low quality shareware coder :-D Pointing out what you failed after others does not negates your failure. Why did you started to  refer to your own software as an authority, anyway? I never heard about it before today.

Comment: @user539484 You are embarrassing yourself!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am/was under the assumption that the global `DecimalSeperator` variable would not be touched by the RTL. If not, then all these routines have an optional parameter `FormatSettings` which you could use. Globaly declare a `TFormatSettings` variable and use it for each occurance of these routines.

A small benefit of it could be that the routines are thread-safe when you specify your own format settings.

Comment: +1, I think this was introduced in Delphi2006. Never rely on a setting of the global `DecimalSeparator`.

Comment: Ah yes, I see I can do a TformatSettings.create('en-UK') to be sure all users get the correct formatting.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was referring to Andy.  You use your own FormatSettings not the global ones.  And one per thread, if there are threads. Secondly you can format things via your own format functions, in some cases, for example, if you have specific binary requirements as per certain vertical systems.  I have written custom formatters too.

Comment: @warren why one per thread? One global instance should suffice.

Comment: @NGLN: Well, it is touched by the RTL. See my answer.

Comment: One global instance is fine unless you are modifying the value from a thread. You obviously don't modify a global instance from multiple threads unless you want to create some interesting race conditions.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, the `DecimalSeparator` global variable might be changed by the RTL during runtime, which caused a lot of headache for me a few years ago before I realised this.

The thing is that `DecimalSeparator` is updated by the RTL when the Windows decimal separator is changed, for instance, using the Control Panel. This might seem like a rather small problem. Indeed, how often does the end user change the system's decimal separator?

The big issue is that the `DecimalSeparator` variable is updated (according to the system setting) *every time you switch user* (in Windows). That came as a surprise to me. That is, if your system setting uses a comma (`','`) as the decimal separator, and you set `DecimalSeparator := '.'` at application startup, then `DecimalSeparator` will revert to a comma if you switch user (and you'll notice that when you switch back).

You can tell the RTL not to update the decimal separator by

```
Application.UpdateFormatSettings := false;
```

At any rate, there are better alternatives to `DecimalSeparator`, as discussed in other answers and comments.

Comment: +1, good to know what take care of to, never heard about `UpdateFormatSettings` property.

Comment: @TLama: It is not a cure without drawbacks though. While it does protect your code from changes by the user to the regional settings, it means your app needs to be closed and restarted before showing the user the dates, times, currencies, etc in the format that they just selected. Keeping UpdateFormatSettings True means your app responds to these changes without having to close first.

Comment: @Marjan, you're right. Maybe the `RM_TaskbarCreated` and `WM_WININICHANGE` catch would be, just like `TApplication.CheckIniChange` function do. If you receive one of them you can tell user to restart the application to reflect changes made by locale settings.

Answer (score 8):

To be on the safe side, i would use `TFormatSettings`, this has two advantages:

1. The formatting is thread safe, other code/libraries cannot influence your function.
2. You do not influence other code, which possibly rely upon certain settings.

Here a possible implementation:

```
function FloatToStrWithDecimalPoint(const Value: Extended; const Format: String = '0.###'): String;
var
  myFormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
begin
  GetLocaleFormatSettings(GetThreadLocale, myFormatSettings);
  myFormatSettings.DecimalSeparator := '.';
  Result := FormatFloat(Format, Value, myFormatSettings);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could patch every string before and after calling a RTL function with some *ForceLocalSeparator()* and *ForceDotSeparator()* functions.

```
// before a RTL call
Function ForceLocalSeparator(Const StrValue: String): String;
Var
  SepPos: Integer;
Begin
  Result := StrValue;
  If DecimalSeparator <> '.' Then
    Begin
      SepPos := Pos( '.', Result );
      If SepPos > 0 Then Result[SepPos] := DecimalSeparator;
    End;
End;

// after a RTL call
Function ForceDotSeparator(Const StrValue: String): String;
Var
  SepPos: Integer;
Begin
  Result := StrValue;
  If DecimalSeparator <> '.' Then
    Begin
      SepPos := Pos( DecimalSeparator, Result );
      If SepPos > 0 Then Result[SepPos] := '.';
    End;
End;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's OK if you have no alternative. Prefer the versions of those functions that accept a `TFormatSettings` parameter, if your Delphi version is recent enough, so that you don't interfere with any other code that relies on that global variable for locale-aware behavior.

`FloatToStr` and `StrToFloat` are locale-sensitive functions. If you need to convert your floating-point value to a string to persist it somewhere that a program will read later (such as to a file, the registry, or a network socket), then you should use the **locale-independent functions `Str` and `Val`** for your conversions instead. They always use `.` for the decimal separator, regardless of the `DecimalSeparator` variable or other environmental settings.

Comment: Hi rob, yes **val** is a useful function, **str** - less so. I have expression evaluators/parsers that use val to determine if the text is a number or not since it gives an error code rather than generating an exception. The output from **str** is not what I require though, I really do need the **ffgeneral** format of **floattostr** although I even have to post process this since I need to display a limited number of digits after the decimal point (even if its in exponential format).

Comment: For what purpose are you converting the numbers to strings? Is it for displaying the numbers, or for storing them? For displaying, you should honor the user's locale preferences. For storing, you should ignore them. `FloatToStr` has no `ffGeneral` format. Are you talking about `FloatToStrF` instead?

Comment: The locale preferences are for consumer applications. For business applications the decision on which separator to use is not location specific, it depends on the standards that are applied to the discipline you are catering too. French Delphi programmers don't use comma's they use periods, that's the standard.