# How to get the character set used for numbers in a Delphi 6 program based on locale?

Tags: delphi, localization, type-conversion

Is there a Windows API call or Delphi call that will tell me what character set Delphi 6 is expecting to be used by numbers by its format conversion routines such as StrToFloat()?  For example, how can I find out if Delphi will expect to see a comma or a period for the decimal point?

Comment: See also this answer to the question: [Is it OK to use DecimalSeparator to force Floattostr/Strtofloat functions to use a decimal point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9816979/576719)

Comment: @LURD.  That's a great link.  Fortunately I am only reading the value of DecimalSeparator and adjusting to it rather than changing it, but that SO post you linked to is invaluable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if [`GetLocaleFormatSettings`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_GetLocaleFormatSettings.html) is available in D6. (but it's not in D5).
You could use [`DecimalSeparator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.DecimalSeparator) global variable (`SysUtils`).

`StrToFloat`:

> The **DecimalSeparator** global variable defines the character that must
>   be used as a decimal point. Thousand separators (**ThousandSeparator**) and currency symbols
>   are not allowed in the string. If S doesn't contain a valid value,
>   StrToFloat raises an EConvertError exception.

`DecimalSeparator` is assigned by the `SysUtils` unit by internally using the [`GetLocaleInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API with `LCType` of `LOCALE_SDECIMAL`, and maintained automatically in the `Forms` unit in response to `WM_SETTINGSCHANGE` (GUI application only).

---

**Edit:**

- [`GetLocaleFormatSettings`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_GetLocaleFormatSettings.html) is available since D7.
- `DecimalSeparator` is deprecated in newer version of Delphi (Use `FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator`).

Comment: Thanks Kobik.  Now I do a simple search and replace for for any decimal points I find in the source strings with DecimalSeparator as per your answer.

Comment: +1. There's also `ShortDateFormat` and other global format settings in `System` that may be helpful to know about as well.